# Scroll Div with Cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, cursor

I have been working with a script by Scripterlative called CursorDivScroll, which scrolls the content of a div based on the cursor position. In my case, I want to scroll content vertically from the right side of the div; not a continuous scroll, but movement that goes a little and then stops so the user has some control. I'm having problems getting the script to work and wondered if anyone knew of a better solution? The script I have uses cursordivscroll.js and this script, which is placed just beneath my div.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' >
     $(document).ready(function() {
  CursorDivScroll( 'repertoiredetails', 40, 10 ).noHorizontal();
     });
 </script>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
 <div id="repertoiredetails">
 <p>content</p>
 </div><!-- close repertoiredetails-->

    #repertoiredetails {
background-color:#000;
width:400px;
opacity:0.7; filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    margin-top:140px;
float:left;
height:auto;    
    display:none;
    margin-left:-2px;
    padding-top:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
    z-index:999;
 }

 #repertoiredetails {
cursor: url(../images/arrow.png), auto;
    position:relative;

 }

 #repertoiredetails p {
  text-align:justify;
  text-justify:inter-word; 
  color:#999; 
  font-family:'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  width:400px;
  padding:20px;
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the associated HTML

Comment: added html and css for clarity purposes-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why the `noHorizontal()` is not working, but with a few changes in your CSS you can make it work.

### a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/M4AXB/1/

Good Luck!

Comment: thank you! I had just fixed this myself by adding height to the div instead of setting it to auto. Is there any way I can set this so the div begins scrolling down when the cursor is at the top of the div also? Right now, the cursor needs to be either at the top or bottom.

Comment: Not according with the configuration included in the **.js** file, but I think with a little hack/modifications you colud do it. Be sure to read the **Read me First** (first 124 lines of .js file).

Comment: Thanks- I sped up the stepFactor a bit which helps.